# XLConnect import the same tab from several excel files including the file name

Tags: excel, filenames, xlconnect

I have around 100 excel files with many tabs.

I would like to:

1. Import the same tab from different files (tabs have the same names
   in all excel files)
2. Add a column with the filename
3. Fuse all imported tabs to 1 table (with the filename as source identifier on each row)

I an very new to R and haven't got very far yet.

Thank you, Veerle

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
require(XLConnect)
require(plyr)

files = c(...)
sheet = "sheetname"

ldply(files, function(file) {
  cbind(file = file, readWorksheetFromFile(file, sheet = sheet)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
    require(XLConnect)

    ListFiles <- list.files(pattern="*.xls")
    ListFiles.short <- ListFiles[1:2]
    sheetname = "Volume"
    all.volume <- data.frame()
    j <- 0

    for (i in ListFiles){
         j<- j+1
         print(j)
         print(i) #prints just to follow the progress of the loop
         wb <- loadWorkbook(i)
         wbsheet <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet=sheetname, startRow=2, header=TRUE, check.names=TRUE)
         wbsheet$filename <- i 
         all.volume <- rbind(all.volume, wbsheet)
         }
```